# find original app ID - for iOS Apple app

Tags: ios, submission

While upgrading an existing app, I'm getting the notorious:

> "The binary you uploaded was invalid. The signature was invalid, or it
>   was not signed with an Apple submission certificate."

I believe it is due to the fact that I am using the wrong App ID. I forgot the one I used in the original app. Is there a way to determine the original App ID? I now using xcode 4 the original app was done back in iOS 3.0 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is available on from the store or if you still have the bundle you submitted open it up and find the binary.  On the binary run

strings - appBinary | grep -A 1 application-identifier

this will show you the appID that was used.

Incidentally this didn't completely solve my problem.  However closely examining the strings on the binary I was trying to submit revealed the app was being signed by my developer cert and not my distribution cert (despite the xcode settings) there fore I changed all builds to use my distribution cert's and it then worked.